# Makefile template for large C++ project?

Tags: c++, makefile

I need a Makefile that will compile everything in the current directory and recursively down the tree, and preferably use the compiler's dependency thing (-M, etc.) so that whenever I type "make", as little as possible is recompiled.

Also, why is this not page 1 of the Makefile documentation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While I would suggest using tools like cmake or alike, I understand that sometimes it is easier or better to use a plain old Makefile.

Here's a Makefile I've used on some projects, it creates dependency-files using gcc:

```
# Project Name (executable)
PROJECT = demoproject
# Compiler
CC = g++

# Run Options       
COMMANDLINE_OPTIONS = /dev/ttyS0

# Compiler options during compilation
COMPILE_OPTIONS = -ansi -pedantic -Wall

#Header include directories
HEADERS =
#Libraries for linking
LIBS =

# Dependency options
DEPENDENCY_OPTIONS = -MM

#-- Do not edit below this line --

# Subdirs to search for additional source files
SUBDIRS := $(shell ls -F | grep "\/" )
DIRS := ./ $(SUBDIRS)
SOURCE_FILES := $(foreach d, $(DIRS), $(wildcard $(d)*.cpp) )

# Create an object file of every cpp file
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(SOURCE_FILES))

# Dependencies
DEPENDENCIES = $(patsubst %.cpp, %.d, $(SOURCE_FILES))

# Create .d files
%.d: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(DEPENDENCY_OPTIONS) $< -MT "$*.o $*.d" -MF $*.d

# Make $(PROJECT) the default target
all: $(DEPENDENCIES) $(PROJECT)

$(PROJECT): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $(PROJECT) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS)

# Include dependencies (if there are any)
ifneq "$(strip $(DEPENDENCIES))" ""
  include $(DEPENDENCIES)
endif

# Compile every cpp file to an object
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -c $(COMPILE_OPTIONS) -o $@ $< $(HEADERS)

# Build & Run Project
run: $(PROJECT)
    ./$(PROJECT) $(COMMANDLINE_OPTIONS)

# Clean & Debug
.PHONY: makefile-debug
makefile-debug:

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(PROJECT) $(OBJECTS)

.PHONY: depclean
depclean:
    rm -f $(DEPENDENCIES)

clean-all: clean depclean
```

Comment: Nice. I put a - before the include (and changed the indentation to tabs) to get this working.